# Invalid bitcode signature on xcode

Tags: xcode, bitcode

After updating Xcode to version 8.3 I'm getting this error:

```
error: Invalid bitcode signature
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Bitcode is not even enabled on my project.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Are you using cocoapods?

Comment: @ParthAdroja yes

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43215407/xcode-invalid-bitcode

Comment: Check your active architecture only property in project settings. Setting it to YES solved my issue.

Answer (score 24):

Try some tricks ->

- [Clear derived data & reopen xcode.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38016143/how-to-delete-derived-data-in-xcode-8/40278559)
- Select proper sign in / certificate, or try to re add account in
  `xcode`
- Make sure if your pods supported bitcode if not then you need to set
  bitcode to NO (Go to Project Build setting search for bitcode & set
  it to NO.

Hope it will helpful:)

Comment: "Clear derived data & reopen xcode." helped me.

Comment: Clear derived data works

Comment: "Clear derived data & reopen xcode." helped me too! Apparently, only clearing derived data is not enough. You have to close and reopen Xcode. I have many situation where closing and reopening Xcode fix it. What's wrong with Xcode nowadays?

Comment: Clearing "derived data": 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38016143/how-to-delete-derived-data-in-xcode-8/40278559

Answer (score 12):

There might be the issues with some third party libraries. I have faced such issues a few days earlier and did following things.

1. Update pod using `pod update`
2. Restart Xcode
3. Clean Project and Build.

If this don't solve the issues please share the podfile so I can know which pods are you using that might cause the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I've followed the steps you've suggested the error is still happening. This is the podfile https://gist.github.com/odedharth/15634abf3be69e4a0617249ce387cf05

Comment: @ParthAdroja what that second part of the Podfile do?

Comment: @AnirudhaMahale Sorry I can't understand your question. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @AnirudhaMahale It will apply build settings for pod build configuration in your xcode project.

Comment: @ParthAdrojaI I have tried the above steps but didn't solve my issues. Will you help me if I share my pods that I have used? Here are the pods that I have used - 1.Alamofire 2.ReachabilitySwift 3. SwiftyJSON 4.Charts 5.XCGLogger 6.OneSignal

Answer (score 2):

Clean and then run the project will help.